# Prototype JavaScript -- function using constructor function

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function user(name) {
    console.log(name);
}

user.prototype.test = function() {
    return 2 + 2;
};

console.log(user.prototype.test());

var dany = new user("dany");
var david = new user("david");

console.log(dany.prototype.test());
```

Console logs:

```
4
dany
david
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'test' of undefined
```

Shouldn't the test() function be assigned to all instances of the user() function (which is the object constructor) ?

If you happen to have good recommendations on what I should read to understand prototype more, please go ahead too ;)

Edit:

Even using:

```
Object.prototype.test = function() {
    return 2 + 2;
};
```

I still get that error in the console. I thought that all objects would inherit that prototype function too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of prototype functions and values as default values for all instances.
Why you're seeing the `TypeError` is because you're trying to call `dany`s prototype and the method `test()` on that.

Try `dany.test()` instead.

[This would be your best bet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) when reading on how it works.

TLDR;

You're getting the `TypeError` because the instance of the `user` function doesn't have its own prototype. You can however access the instances prototype via the `__proto__` shortcut.